# How to solve this in Laravel 6? Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

**My Model**

```
class Purchase extends Model
{
  public function supplier()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class,'supplier_id','id');
  }

  public function unit()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Unit::class,'unit_id','id');
  }

  public function category()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category_id','id');
  }

  public function product()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class,'product_id','id');
  }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
class PurchaseController extends Controller
{
  public function view()
  {
    $data['allData'] = Purchase::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    return view('backend.purchase.view-purchases', $data);
  }
```

**My View Page**

```
@foreach($allData as $key => $purchase)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $loop->index + 1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ $purchase->purchase_no }}</td>
      <td>{{ $purchase->product->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $purchase->unit->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $purchase->date }}</td>
      and 2 more td for edit and delete
@endforeach
```

But there's still errors in all `{{ $purchase-> example}}`.  I can't find the errors.  If I check the `dd()` method right after the `tr` tag it works but it doesn't get the `{{ $purchase-> example }}`. I have the following error message:

```
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\POS\resources\views\backend\purchase\view-purchases.blade.php).
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXAkf.png)

Comment: Show us the result of `dd($purchase->product)` and `dd($purchase->unit)`.

Comment: Just curious, How you access the `$allData` here? Cause you defined it as a key on the `$data` array. `@foreach($data['allData'] as $key => $purchase)`

Comment: 'App\Model\Product {#1286 ▼
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "products"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:11 [▶]
  #original: array:11 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}'

Comment: It starts showing the error in the first Td ,,, {{ $purchase->purchase_no }} and there is an exact coloumn purchase_no in my table...

Comment: and @dd($purchase->unit). shows null..

Comment: So `$purchase->unit->name` will give you `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object` because your purchase doesn't have a unit associated to it, you can also do `optional($purchase->unit)->name`

Comment: if i remove the joining table data {{ $purchase->product->name }} and {{ $pirchase->unit->name }} then it works,, so i think i have forgotten to add unit_id  coloumn in purchases table?? isn't it?

Comment: Maybe so double check `unit_id` and `product_id`

Comment: it has worked broo,, thank you so much

Comment: i just wrote this <td>{{ $purchase->product->unit->name }}</td>

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

Try loading the relations in the controller e.g.

```
$data['allData'] = Purchase::with('supplier', 'unit', 'category', 'product')->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

I would also advise you to change your controller view method body to the following.

```
$purchases = Purchase::with('supplier', 'unit', 'category', 'product')->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
return view('backend.purchase.view-purchases')->with(['purchases' => $purchases]);
```

So then in your view try to access it like the following.

```
@foreach($purchases as $purchase)
...
<td>{{ $purchase->purchase_no }}</td>
...
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks bro... it has been solved . My problem was in database relationship